# SQL Conditions, one definite others variable

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM UserTags
    INNER JOIN Events ON UserTags.E_ID=Events.E_ID
WHERE ID = 2
  AND Tag='coffee'
  OR Tag='breakfast_brunch'
  OR Tag='scandinavian'
```

This is returning the incorrect result, as it is returning columns where `ID!=2'. I believe this its trying to match the first two, followed by the others? I would like the query to only match when ID=2 in any situation.

Comment: In your `WHERE` clause you need: ... `AND` **(**... `OR` ... `OR` ... **)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM UserTags INNER JOIN Events ON UserTags.E_ID=Events.E_ID WHERE ID = 2 AND (Tag='coffee' OR Tag='breakfast_brunch' OR Tag='scandinavian')
```

If you think of it as the first condition must be true (ID = 2) and one of the subsequent ones must be true then putting it in the brackets means you compare condition1 AND condition2, where condition 2 is the result of your OR statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM UserTags 
INNER JOIN Events ON UserTags.E_ID=Events.E_ID 
WHERE ID = 2 AND 
    (Tag='coffee' OR Tag='breakfast_brunch' OR Tag='scandinavian')
```

Read this article about `AND` `OR` ordering: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/126-SQL-AND-OR-Order-of-Operations.htm